# how to render part of the page and not all components

Tags: reactjs

This is how my component looks like:

```
import React, { useState, forwardRef, useImperativeHandle } from "react";
import { Form, Input, Label, Segment, Header } from "semantic-ui-react";


const VendorSignupForm = forwardRef(({ data }, ref) => {

    const [vendorSignupData, setVendorSignupData] = useState({})
    const [errorMessages, setErrorMessages] = useState({})

    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
        return {
            vendorSignupData: vendorSignupData,
            setVendorSignupData: setVendorSignupData,
            setErrorMessages: setErrorMessages
        };
    });

    const handleChange = e => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setVendorSignupData(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            [name]: value
        }));
    };

    return (
        <Form>
            <Header block attached='top'>
                Signup Information
            </Header>
            <Segment color='orange' attached>
                <Form.Group widths='equal'>
                    <Form.Input label="Username (Email Address)" placeholder="Email Address" defaultValue={vendorSignupData.username} name="username" onChange={handleChange} error={errorMessages.username} />
                    <Form.Input label="Password" placeholder="Password" defaultValue={vendorSignupData.password} name="password" onChange={handleChange} error={errorMessages.password} />
                    <Form.Input label="Confirm Password" placeholder="Retype password" defaultValue={vendorSignupData.confirmpassword} name="confirmpassword" onChange={handleChange} error={errorMessages.confirmpassword} />
                </Form.Group>
            </Segment>

        </Form>
    );

});

export default VendorSignupForm;
```

This is how the parent form looks like:

```
import { vendorSignup, doVendorSignup } from "../../webapi/vendor_signup";
import VendorSignupForm from "../../components/VendorSignupForm";
import { Grid, Image, Item, Label, Button, Icon, Form, Message } from "semantic-ui-react";
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import UIFeedback from "../../components/UIFeedback";


const VendorSignupFormParent = ({ user, data }) => {
    const vendorSignupFormRef = useRef(null);
    const [uiFeedbackMessage, setUIFeedbackMessage] = useState()
    const [uiFeedbackType, setUIFeedbackType] = useState()




    async function handleClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        let ret = await doVendorSignup(vendorSignupFormRef.current.vendorSignupData)
        if (ret.type) {
            if (ret.type == "validation") {
                console.log("validation errors")
                vendorSignupFormRef.current.setErrorMessages(ret.err)
            }
            else {
                setUIFeedbackType(ret.type) # <-- This call resets the data to blank
                setUIFeedbackMessage(ret.errors)
            }

        }
        else {
            if (ret.success) {
                console.log("all good")
            }
        }
    };


    function DisplayProperControl({ data }) {
        return (
            <div>
                <React.Fragment>
                    <Grid columns={1}>
                        <Grid.Row>
                            <Grid.Column>
                                <VendorSignupForm data={data} ref={vendorSignupFormRef}></VendorSignupForm>
                            </Grid.Column>
                        </Grid.Row>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid.Row>
                        <Grid.Column>
                            <Button onClick={handleClick}>
                                Signup
                    </Button>
                        </Grid.Column>

                    </Grid.Row>
                </React.Fragment>
                <React.Fragment>
                    <Grid.Row>
                        <Grid.Column>
                            <UIFeedback type={uiFeedbackType} message={uiFeedbackMessage}></UIFeedback>
                        </Grid.Column>
                    </Grid.Row>
                </React.Fragment>
            </div>
        );
    }

    return (

        <DisplayProperControl data={data}></DisplayProperControl>

    )
};


export default VendorSignupFormParent;
```

When user clicks on `Signup` button, I make an AJAX call and display what the server returns on the page using `UIFeedback` component but that resets the data in `VendorSignupForm` to blank (initial data) which I believe is due to re-rendering of all the components.

Since the data already exists on the page, how do I avoid doing that without sending the submitted data back from the server?

Comment: `DisplayProperControl` function is being redefined on every render. its not typical to define components inside each other. define it outside and pass props

Comment: you mean outside `VendorSignupFormParent`? Can you please provide an example?

Comment: yes just like any other component

Comment: I'm guessing your data is clearing because the ref is being reassigned to the component on every render. if you only declare the omponent once the ref won't be reassigned all the time

Comment: I'm guessing your data is clearing because the ref is being reassigned to the component on every render. if you only declare the omponent once the ref won't be reassigned all the time

Comment: Ok. I am trying to do that now.

Comment: Thank you. Got it working. If you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it.